# Programmatically power off the machine by Machine name?

Tags: windows, system-shutdown

I want to write the utility which will be scheduled task, and will take the list of computer names on domain. After a particular time which will be set in the utility machines with that name get shutdown.

Please share your thoughts on this...

Thanks.
Anjan

Comment: Windows, unix, mac, linux, computerized coffee machines?

Comment: Hi James,

Windows machine. Sorry for incomplete information in question...

Comment: Hi Earlz,

Language is not an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at (C#)

[Shutdown[Remote] Using Shutdown.exe](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/RemoteShutdown.aspx?fid=965424&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick)